# Downloading file in cgi perl script

Tags: perl, cgi, download

I am unable to download the file in cgi perl. Instead I get the contents printed on the web page itself.This is what I had tried.

**Code:**

```
use CGI qw /:standard /;
use CGI;

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
my $files_location;
my $ID;
my @fileholder;

$directorypath = "/var/www/cgi-bin/";        
$files_location = $directorypath;
$ID = 'file.txt';
#$ID = param('ID');  

if ($ID eq '') {  
print "You must specify a file to download.";  
} else {  

open(DLFILE, "<$files_location/$ID") || Error('open', 'file');  
@fileholder = <DLFILE>;  
close (DLFILE) || Error ('close', 'file');  

#these are the html codes that forces the browser to open for download  
print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n";  
print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$ID\n\n";  
print @fileholder;  
}
```

**I am getting this:**

```
Content-Type:application/x-download Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=file.txt ih how are u iam hre
```

**file.txt**

ih how are u iam hre

Answer (score 3):

On line 4 you've got:

```
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
```

That double `\n` signals end-of-headers, content will follow. Get rid of that and try again?

Comment: Still I get the same.No change

Comment: Let me be more specific. Please comment out or remove entirely line 4 in your script. Still the same results?

Comment: ok I got this working when I copied that download code to a script named download.pl and added the following line to my original script
print "<br><br><a href=\"/cgi-bin/download.pl\" target=\"_blank\">Download file</a><br><br>\n";

Answer (score 0):

try commenting

```
    print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must move the below line from top to inside if loop:

```
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
```

To

```
if ($ID eq '') {  
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print "You must specify a file to download.";  
}
```